# How to save an animation to mp4 successfully

Tags: animation, matplotlib, save, mp4

I am using the `ani=anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, frames=20` syntax with an `animate` function which I then want to save to a file for later viewing. I have tried saving the file with `ani.save('plan_evap.mp4', fps=1)` but this process of saving seems to be the limiting factor to my whole end. The resulting mp4 movie that is obviously problematic can be downloaded here (http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00603708182366713933) for view. I would apprecaite any help people can offer to help resolve this.

Comment: A wild guess, do you have tight bounding boxes set in your rcparams?  Can you provide a minimal example of code to generate the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by tight-bounding boxes? Can you provide more detail about this, as I have changed my matplotlibrc file from the default and this may indeed be the cause.

Comment: I have just restored the matplotlibrc parameters to their default values and it now seems to work for some reason, but I did not see any option in the matplotlibrc file for bounding_box=tight. How does one improve the movie quality of the resulting movie?